# How can I make a loop at the same time in columns and rows for setting a zero in some positions of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, row

I have a data frame with 14000 rows and information associate in the columns 2010 to 2050 those represent years. I need to set a zero where the year (df.columns - 2010 to 2050) is greater than the value associate to the column year_out (for instance in the first row the value is 2020)

```
years = np.arange(2013,2050)
rows  = np.arange(0, 14000)

df
    Plan         2010  2020  2030  2040  2050  year_out
0  Australia     500   500   500   500   500    2020  
1  Australia     400   400   400   400   400    2020  
2  New Zealand   300   300   300   300   300    2020  
3  New Zealand   200   200   200   200   200    2020
```

I have tried

```
for df.columns in years:
for df.index in rows:
df.loc[df.index, "year_out"]
    if df.loc[df.index, "year_out"] > df.columns:
        #print('yes')
        df.loc[df.index, df.columns] = 0
```

I would like to get

```
    Plan         2010  2020  2030  2040  2050  year_out
0  Australia     500   500     0     0     0    2020  
1  Australia     400   400   400     0     0    2030  
2  New Zealand   300   300   300     0     0    2040  
3  New Zealand   200   200   200   200     0    2050
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You wrote: "I need to set a zero where the year...is less than the value associate to the column `year_out`", but in your expected output you have set 0 for all the years *greater* than `year_out`.  Which do you want?

Comment: all of your `year_out` values in your example data equal `2020`, but in your expected output, the `year_out` values are different.  can you please update to be consistent?

Comment: I think he showed the first few rows of his 14000 row df, but he made his output reflect if he had each year as a row.

Comment: @andrew_reece just think about the first row, the value in the column year_out is 2020, then I would like to compare the head of the columns 2010, 2020, 2030, 2040 and 2050 with 2020. If 2010 (head of the column)  is > 2020 (value in the position (0,year_output) then set zero in the position (0 , 2010), if not keep the value 500 and so on. I want to do for all the rows.

Comment: @andrew_reece you are right, I want greater than

Comment: In your expected output, you use `>` to compare against `year_out` for row index 2 and 3, but `>=` for row index 0 and 1.  please update to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use Pandas `apply` and update each row based on its `year_out` value:

```
def updater(row):
    for col in row.index:
        try:
            if int(col) >= row['year_out']:
                row[col] = 0
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return row

df.apply(updater, axis=1)
          Plan  2010  2020  2030  2040  2050  year_out
0    Australia   500     0     0     0     0      2020
1    Australia   400   400     0     0     0      2030
2  New Zealand   300   300   300     0     0      2040
3  New Zealand   200   200   200   200     0      2050
```

With example data:

```
data =  {'Plan': {0: 'Australia', 1: 'Australia', 2: 'New Zealand', 3: 'New Zealand'},
 '2010': {0: 500, 1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 200},
 '2020': {0: 500, 1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 200},
 '2030': {0: 500, 1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 200},
 '2040': {0: 500, 1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 200},
 '2050': {0: 500, 1: 400, 2: 300, 3: 200},
 'year_out': {0: 2020, 1: 2030, 2: 2040, 3: 2050}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
          Plan  2010  2020  2030  2040  2050  year_out
0    Australia   500   500   500   500   500      2020
1    Australia   400   400   400   400   400      2030
2  New Zealand   300   300   300   300   300      2040
3  New Zealand   200   200   200   200   200      2050
```

Note: Your expected output seems to alternate between setting columns to zero when they are either `>=` vs `>` than `year_out`.  I'm assuming that's an error, and I've set a consistent rule in this answer (easy to change if need be).

Comment: I got KeyError: ('year_out', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @EsperanzaGonzález, can you please confirm that you are testing this solution on the exact example data I used?  I tried to replicate your original example data exactly.  Based on the error you are getting, it looks like your axis is reversed in your actual data.  But please confirm that the solution works on the sample data first.  Then we can try and figure out what is different between the data you provided and your actual data.

Comment: @andrew_race I pasted the example data you pasted and I am getting AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: sorry, forgot to wrap the dict in `pd.DataFrame()`.  i'll update now.

Comment: Thank you dear Andrew, it works in the example. I could't figure out my problem in my data frame yet because I have several columns which are not integer (several columns with strings). For the question I just pick the columns which I want to make the calculation. Actually I am not sure if it is the problem. I am new in python :(. I am getting KeyError: ('year_out', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Hmm - I think there's something about your data which isn't represented correctly in your question.  (Either that or I'm not understanding.)  My answer tries to convert string columns to integers, and if a string is not a string representation of an integer, then nothing happens (and it continues without error).  But maybe you mean that you have other columns which are either integers or string representations of integers, besides the ones you want to adjust?  If so, please include relevant example data in your post.  (I'm still not sure why that would produce the axis error you were getting.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way from `numpy` boradcast

```
youcolumns=['2010','2020','2030','2040','2050']
v=pd.DataFrame(df[youcolumns].columns.values.astype(int)<df.year_out.values[:,None],columns=youcolumns,index=df.index)
df[youcolumns]=df[youcolumns][v]
df[youcolumns]=df[youcolumns].fillna(0)
df

Out[151]: 
   2010   2020   2030   2040  2050         Plan  year_out
0   500    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    Australia      2020
1   400  400.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    Australia      2030
2   300  300.0  300.0    0.0   0.0  New Zealand      2040
3   200  200.0  200.0  200.0   0.0  New Zealand      2050
```